# How likely does my data in Firebase Realtime Database to disappear?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Im proposing my client to use Firebase Realtime Database as their backend storage sever but my client reluctant to use it as they have never heard of it and is more leaning towards common server like AWS.

How can I approach them to use Firebase as this is the only backend I deeply understood.

And how likely does data in Firebase Realtime Database lost?

Has anyone ever experience data lost on Firebase Realtime Database before?

Thanks.

Comment: The storage reliability of most large-scale databases, whether Firebase, AWS, Azure, etc is going to be far more reliable than a developer's own human error (i.e. bugs in the actual program being deployed, which forget to save/introduce corruption/etc). You may want to consider focusing on steps that mitigate both application-layer bugs that can occur, and the infra level bugs that your client is concerned about - e.g. backups.

Comment: From personal experience, Firebase is rock solid and has redundancy and backups. I would recommend it. Other than that though - this is really asking for opinions which is generally off-topic for SO. Do you have a situation where you've lost data? If so, is there a coding example or more info?

Comment: Even if asking for opinions on StackOverflow is forbidden, I can tell you from my experience, that I have never lost a bit of data, so you should give it a try.

Comment: @Jay because they will use it to store a map coordinate, so to get these data, they need to spend lots of time and money, so they arent willing to collect those coordinate again just in case something happened to Firebase and the data is all gone and they dont wanna store any backup else where because it might be stolen or lost. So they need a server that is extremely reliable. I guess nothing will ever happen to their data if its stored in Firebase, but I am lack of experience as I am a new developer so just asking for the experience from other experts here so I will be able to convince them.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is a subset of Google Cloud Platform.  Most people know GCP, but less people know about Firebase.  The technologies of Firebase are fundamental to GCP and to many of Google's products.  Firebase RTDB has been around a long, long time and has many thousands (millions??) of apps using it.  So to put confidence in your customer, I would lean on "Google" and get them to recognize that "Firebase is Google/GCP".